# Updating a large Resultset with JDBC and MySQL

Tags: java, database, jdbc, resultset

I am trying update a large set of rows (around 5M). I first came across the heap overflow issue of having so many rows fetched in a resultset. Since I don't want to raise my heap size on this machine I was wondering if there is an effective way of doing this.

I tried setting the `setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE)` but then when I call the update function I get this error:

Streaming result set `com.mysql.jdbc.RowDataDynamic@2087c268` is still active. No statements may be issued when any streaming result sets are open and in use on a given connection. Ensure that you have called `.close()` on any active streaming result sets before attempting more queries.

If I call `close()` on the result set I cannot update it of course. Here is my code

```
public void getRows()
    {
         Statement stmt = null;
         ResultSet rs = null;
         int countSpecialChars = 0;
         int upper = 0, lower = 0, digits =0;
         String pass = null;
         int id = 0;

         char thisChar;
         String query = "select id,pass from datatable";
            try {
              this.conn.setAutoCommit(false);
              stmt = this.conn.createStatement();
              stmt.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
              rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

          while (rs.next()) {
                   pass = rs.getString(2).trim();
                   id = rs.getInt(1);
            for (int i=0; i<=pass.length()-1; i++)
             {
                thisChar= pass.charAt(i);
                    if (thisChar >= 65 && thisChar <= 90) {
                    upper++; 
                } else if (thisChar >= 97 && thisChar <= 122) {
                    lower++;
                }  else if( thisChar >= 48 && thisChar <= 57) {
                    digits++;
                }
                else
                {countSpecialChars++;}
             }
                Entropy entropy = new Entropy();
                double naiveEntropy = entropy.naiveEntropy(pass);
             NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");
             this.updateRow(id, pass.length(), digits, upper, lower, countSpecialChars, Double.parseDouble(formatter.format(naiveEntropy)));
             countSpecialChars = 0;
             upper=digits=0;
             lower = 0;
          }
            rs.close();
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        ...
    }

    public void updateRow(int id, int length, int numbers, int upper, 
            int lower, int specialChars, double naiveEntropy )
    {
        PreparedStatement updatePassEntry = null;

        String updateString = "update cwlCompatiblePassUnique " +
        "set length = ?, numbers = ?, upper = ?, lower = ?, specialChars = ?, ShannonEntropy = ?  where id = ?";
        try {
             this.conn.setAutoCommit(false);
             updatePassEntry = this.conn.prepareStatement(updateString);
             updatePassEntry.setInt(1, length);
             ...
             updatePassEntry.setInt(7, id);
             updatePassEntry.executeUpdate();
             this.conn.commit();
         }
        catch (SQLException e)
        ...         
    }
```

Any ideas on what can be done?

Thanks

Comment: try to create a new connection and use that one to update to database. hope this will help.

Comment: This is the correct answer. MySQL wire protocol does not support multiple statement execution on the same connection at the same time. So if one really needs 2 commands either the full result of the first command must be completely read (this is "not streaming" mode), or you can "stream" the result with one connection, and update via second one.

Answer (score 2):

you call updateRow()  method inside the rs.next() loop; which tries to make a SQL update on a SQL field (id) that is currently being processed inside your while (rs.next()) loop. this will raise the error you get.  i suggest you write a method for pulling rs and storing them in java objects vector as a first step. this method will close the rs after exiting. then write another method to do both processing and update data on your cached vector objects .
something like this:

```
    private void Vector<DataSet> getDataSet(){
    Vector<DataSet> data=new Vector<DataSet>();
     String query = "select id,pass from datatable";
                try {
                  this.conn.setAutoCommit(false);
                  stmt = this.conn.createStatement();
                  stmt.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
                  rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

                   while (rs.next()) {
                       pass = rs.getString(2).trim();
                       id = rs.getInt(1);
                       data.addElement(new DataSet(id,pass));
                     }

                }catch(Exception e){

    // here close connection and rs
    }
}
    private void udpateData(Vector<dataSet> data){
    //process data and update her
    }

    static class DataSet{
    int id;
    String pass;
    //constructor here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Connection object should not hold multiple resultset object at a time.
After creation of ResultSet and Statement Objects, each has to close explicitly like,
resultSet.close()
statement.close()